# Capture the name of the previous processor in NiFi

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I'm looking to create an Error Handling Flow, and need to capture the name of the failing processor on particular points only. An Update Attribute would be last resort as it would clutter up the templates. Ideally I'm looking for a script or similar, but I'm open to suggestions from NiFi experts.

Comment: What have you tried? Folks here expect to see some effort in the form of a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Data Provenance](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#data_provenance) feature for this via manual inspection or REST API, but by design ("[Flow Based Programming](http://www.jpaulmorrison.com/fbp/)"), components in Apache NiFi are black boxes independent and unaware of their predecessors and successors.

If you need a programmatic capability to access the error messages, look at [`SiteToSiteBulletinReportingTask`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-site-to-site-reporting-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.reporting.SiteToSiteBulletinReportingTask/). With this component, you can send the bulletins back to the same (or a different) NiFi instance via Site-to-Site and ingest and process them as any other arbitrary data.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I'll give these a look